# get TexnicCenter alpha 3 to reuse open window by default?

Tags: texniccenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TexnicCenter: Multiple tabs in ONE window instead of Multiple Instances (Multiple Windows)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49705/texniccenter-multiple-tabs-in-one-window-instead-of-multiple-instances-multipl)

I've noticed that when I double click on a .tex file, Texnic Center keeps opening a new window for each file.  I would rather that all files just be opened in the same window.  Is there a setting for this?

I'm running Texnic Center alpha 3 / windows 7

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll work, but perhaps replace the `open` action in the Windows 7 Registry for TeXnicCenter by something like this: `"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TEXCNTR.EXE" /ddecmd "[open('%1')]"`. Note that from Windows Vista on, this procedure became trickier as you need to edit the registry itself or use a third-party tool, like [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/).

Comment: This is a borderline question for tex.sx. While it is about a TeX-related editor, the actual action required is either a Windows change or something for the TeXniccenter developers. @kristi, have you tried asking the TeXniccenter developers about this?

Comment: Okay, a newer version of the same issue has come up with an answer. So this is now a duplicate!

Comment: About this question being a 'borderline issue for tex.sx': I don't agree. The FAQ states explicitly: "If you have a question about ... (c) Distributions like TeX Live, MiKTeX, and MacTeX, ... (d) Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc." I interprete this as covering TeXnicCenter for sure ! Where the actual action lies is not relevant, helping users in figuring that out or understanding that, is.