# Sumatra inverse search opens a new instance of Texnic Center

Tags: texniccenter, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I have a little problem with SumatraPDF inverse search. I followed [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116981/how-to-configure-texniccenter-2-0-with-sumatra-2013-2014-2015-version) for configuration. 
When I click "view output", Sumatra shows my PDF (which is a good start), but when I click on a word in the PDF to use the inverse search feature, it opens a new instance of TexnicCenter. Does someone know how to solve this? It should be a character to change in the command line but I can't figure it out.

I am using TexnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1 and Sumatra 3.0 and my command line is :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe"\ /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

By the way, I tried to modify Windows 7 registry according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49705/texniccenter-multiple-tabs-in-one-window-instead-of-multiple-instances-multipl) and it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your command line.  The `\` after `TeXnicCenter.exe` has to be before `"`. So please correct the call for SumatraPDF to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

With the current versions of SumatraPDF (version 3.0) and TeXnicCenter (version 2.2) the inverse search runs like a charm.

If you have installed the 64 bit version of TeXnicCenter please change `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter` to `C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, with using the **default configuration** that Texniccenter (2.02 x64) created automatically at the first start after installation.

The problem was that there were no Quotes `"` around the first part of the command in the field mentioned by the OP:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

vs.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

The quotes fixed the issue.

Comment: The problem pointed out by @Mensch is another issue that probably fixed it for the OP. Technically, I'm not answering the OP's question, but I guess someone coming through might still benefit from this.